# python ldap "Bad search filter" error

Tags: ldap

This filter works just fine in my LDAP browser by python ldap won't pick it up:

```
(&(!objectClass=computer)(sn=*%s*))
```

resulting in:

```
Request Method: GET Request
URL: http://localhost:8000/ldap_find/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82/
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: FILTER_ERROR
Exception Value: {'desc': 'Bad search filter'}
```

here's the code that does it:

```
try:
    LDAPClient.connect()
    base = AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH_BASE
    scope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
    filter = '(&(!objectClass=computer)(sn=*%s*))' % search_string
    result_set = list()
    result = LDAPClient.client.search(base.encode(encoding='utf-8'), scope, filter.encode(encoding='utf-8'),['cn','mail'])
    res_type, res_data = LDAPClient.client.result(result)
    for data in res_data:
        if data[0]:
            result_set.append(data)
    return json.dumps(result_set)
except Exception, e:
    raise e
finally:
    LDAPClient.unconnect()
```

it works fine with simple filters, like

```
filter = 'sn=*%s*' % search_string
```

so I'm guessing this is some kind of escaping of & or something inside ldap lib but can't find the root yet.

Comment: I figured this is the '!' before 'objectClass', weird stuff

Comment: *Imaginary* stuff. There is no such syntax.

Comment: I found exactly that imaginary syntax on a Microsoft Technet posting for AD filters. Always be aware that Microsoft likes to do things the wrong way.

Comment: The issue I had was having a comma in between the parenthesis of the filter like this:  
(&(objectClass=*) , (sn=*%s*)) # remove comma in middle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The search filter syntax is incorrect. Use `(&(sn=*%s*)(!(objectClass=computer)))`. Search filters are well-documented in [RFC4511](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511) and [RFC4515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4515).